# Angular 2 NG Grid Fluid Columns

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Is it at all possible to have a grid where the columns have widths that aren't explicitly pixel based? This would be especially useful when used in conjunction with `sizeColumnsToFit()`.

For example, in the following table, the visual design might call for the ID and Name fields to just fit the content, but then have the Description fill the rest of the width of the containing element.

```
| ID | Name  | Description    |
|----|-------|----------------|
| 1  | Foo   | Something foo  |
| 2  | Bar   | Something bar  |
```

Currently, using `sizeColumnsToFit()` makes them all the same width (so a `tableWidth / 3` kind of thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you still need to supply a width in my suggestion, it does allow for ones that are more "dynamic" to be accommodated.

First, set a width for columns that you want to be smaller/fixed:

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: "Column 1",
        field: "col1",
        width:20
    },
```

The hook into the gridReady event to resize the remaining columns (which wont have a width set):

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    onGridReady: () => {
        $scope.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
    ...other properties
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use width property of the grid in column definitions and bind it to a function which can return width in percentage.

```
width: this.columnWidth(windowWidth, 10)

private columnWidth(windowWidth:number, columnSize:number) {
    return Math.floor((windowWidth * columnSize) / 100);
}
```